# How to freeze particular column in Excel sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I freeze particular column in excel sheet ?
Example : I want to freeze column J for entire worksheet.

I have gone through many solutions but they only talks about column A. but I want to freeze other columns except Column A.

Comment: You should post the code you have tried or have in progress so we can assist better.

Comment: There is no code. I am trying to freeze specific column in excel sheet itself. I had tried Excel Freeze Panes option but it freeze only first column. couldn't find any other option.

Comment: https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/freeze-rows-excel-2016

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting J,1 then View->Freeze Panes->Freeze Panes

The Freeze Panes option always freezes the top left corner of a selected cell